# How to find module name for angularjs provider?

Tags: angularjs

This is a seriously dumb question, but I always struggle with this so hopefully someone can help.

When creating my angular app I understand that in order to inject the correct provider, I first need to include it/require it when I define my module.

Here is an example - here I require the $routeProvider, so I include ngRoute:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      $routeProvider.
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'home/about',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'home/contact',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/about'
        });
  }]);
```

Now I additionally require the $locationProvider but don't know what module to include, I look in all the angularjs docs and try ngLocation but no luck! My question (is not which module do I need for location) but rather how do I find out from the angular docs which module I need for any given provider?

I cant figure it out from the crazy documentation?

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute', '?????']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      $routeProvider.
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'home/about',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'home/contact',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/about'
        });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) you can find the documentation for the `$locationProvider`. At the top of the screen, below the title $locationProvider, it says the module where you can find this function, it says "provider in module ng", which means it is part of the core.

Answer (score 1):

In the API Reference the module names are listed as headings in the left navigation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api

For example you can see ngRoute there, and see that $locationProvider is included in the ng module.

Answer (score 0):

`$locationProvider` is in core `ng` module so you don't have to include any other module in order to use `$locationProvider`.